# pluck how to display multiple columns in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to display multiple columns from data base 
value() displays one column 
can pluck display multiple columns??

```
$cat= category::query()->where('id', '=', $id)->value('dia_yes');

// $cat= category::query()->where('id', '=', $id)->pluck('dia_yes','advice')
```

Comment: `value` displays a single value and `pluck` displays one column optionally keyed by another column. if you want more columns use `select('dia_yes','advice','another')->get()`

Comment: I want to display more values of columns select displays
[{"dia_yes":"\u0627\u062d\u062a\u0645\u0627\u0644 \u0644\u062f\u064a\u0643 \u0646\u0632\u0644\u0647 \u0645\u0639\u0648\u064a\u0647 \u064a\u062c\u0628 \u0645\u0631\u0627\u062c\u0639\u0647 \u0637\u0628\u064a\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0627\u0637\u0646\u0647","advice":"\u0

Comment: @Hala can you rephrase this in the form of a question, and show your research you have done already? Otherwise it might get some downvotes :/

Comment: @ Nathan Basanese i have 2 columns want to display there values 
i know that value() display the content of one column ,my question is what can i use to display the content of multiple columns ?